# how to choose the tuning parameter value in regularization for an underdetermined system of equations?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization, least-squares, regularization

Suppose I have # features> #observations while solving a simple linear regression,OLS fails. But Regularized regression is known to solve this problem.

1. But how do I choose Lambda (tuning parameter) value? 
   My understanding is, lambda is chosen based on Cross validation (for which I need more data and that is not possible here because the number of observations I have is already limited)
2. Using pseudo inverse (moore penrose shown below) to solve the underdetermined system did return certain finite coefficients. But on what basis is this done? (considering there can be infinite solutions)
   (below is the equation is used to solve)

[image]

Comment: How "limited" is your data?

Comment: @jbowman Have around 50 observations and 65 features. Most of the features seem useless and i can actually remove them But I want to understand how would one deal with p>n in general.